# How does Jira Issue Security limit a user's access to a specific issue?

Tags: jira

I want to make it so certain users can view and/or comment on specific issues, but not all issues. I was reading that I can use Issue Security for this but I'm not understanding one thing.

My understanding:

1. Enable Issue Security to a project
2. Issue security scheme defined with who can view/comment on issues by specifying Jira groups in the Issue Security settings:

   - group ABC can view
   - group DEF can view + comment
3. People get added to those groups

But, what controls the issue they can access?

If Joe is added to group ABC, what says they can view issue 123 BUT NOT issue 456?

Answer (score 0):

Every issue has a security level, which can be chosen among those that are available in the Issue Security Scheme associated to that project. I suppose you haven't created them yet: then you need to edit the Issue Security Scheme and add all the security levels that you need. [More info on security levels here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-issue-level-security-938847117.html).

In your case, if you want a simple model you could call the security levels something like "Public" and "Restricted". Issue 123 is set to Public, issue 456 to Restricted, and to view restricted issues you must belong to group DEF, so those that are only in group ABC cannot see them.

If you want to manage multiple customers/suppliers and keep things separated, you can create a group for each company, and a security level for each: visible_by_company_A, visible_by_company_B, and so on. Then each security level is configured so that they are visible only be the right groups/roles, and then users must be assigned to the right groups or roles. A user could belong to both groups, or to just one (or to none).
The catch is that each issue can have only one security level, so if you need an issue to be visible by both company A and company B you must create a specific security level for that, like "visible_by_A_and_B", and this doesn't scale well. But in general this rarely happens (at least in my experience), and I've never needed to create too many levels.

One last thing: users who want to set the security level must have the "Set issue security" permission, make sure they have it.

Comment: But if someone is in group DEF, they would get access to every issue that is set to restricted. How do we say that Joe can see Issue 1, and Sue can see Issue 2.

Comment: Issue 1 and 2 must be set to different security levels, and access to those security levels must be granted to members of different groups, where Joe belongs to one and Sue  belongs to the other. This is very similar to my example with Company_A and Company_B.

Comment: I see. If we have hundreds, or thousands of folks and issues, this could become unmanageable.

Comment: If you have to assign every single issue to a single user, yes. But this is an unlikely scenario. Can't you group users based on their team or their role in the company? Then you'd only need a security level per team/role, not one per user. Of course if the issues are about strictly personal data (like performance review of individual employees), then you are right, it would become unmanageable, and you'd better choose another tool.

Comment: Could we create a people field in an issue and configure issue security to grant access to people in that field?

Comment: I'm not sure. The [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-issue-level-security-938847117.html) does say that "A security level's members may consist of: [...] A (multi-)user or (multi-)group picker custom field.", but I don't think the picker is per issue. It's probably bound to the security level, so I'd say no. But it's worth exploring. Unfortunately I can't help you much here, because I'm not working as a Jira administrator anymore (that was a previous job).

Comment: By the way, one thing I hadn't thought of is that the security level can be configured to "Current Assignee". So you can assign an issue to a user, and only that user can see it. If you need issues to be visible only by the assignee and a fixed user or group, like the assignee's managers, that would work!